# Resized image size is larger than original image

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, image-size

I am facing an interesting issue when re-sizing images of average dimension 1200x700. I am using following method to do the same. I see original image size is 210KB and output image size is 255KB.

```
    public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, Size size, bool preserveAspectRatio = true)
    {
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;
        if (preserveAspectRatio)
        {
            int originalWidth = imageFile.Width;
            int originalHeight = imageFile.Height;
            float percentWidth = (float)size.Width / (float)originalWidth;
            float percentHeight = (float)size.Height / (float)originalHeight;
            float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;
            newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
            newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);
        }
        else
        {
            newWidth = size.Width;
            newHeight = size.Height;
        }
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphicsHandle.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(imageFile, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        return newImage;
    }
```

To call above method I'm using following code:

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(remoteFileLocation))))
            {
                Image resized = ResizeImage(image, new Size(660, 660));
                resized.Save(saveFileLocation);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            //todo
        }
```

I tried different InterpolationMode and CompositingQuality but result is always same. Is there anything I'm missing to reduce image dimension and size? I mean, I'm expecting if dimension is decreased image size should also decrease.

Comment: What format are you using to save the image? If, for example, you are using PNG or especially JPEG, these formats produce output of varying size depending on the exact compression implementation used and various settings provided to the compression algorithm. And naturally, if you are _changing_ formats, especially if the original is in a lossy format like JPEG and you are saving to a non-lossy format like PNG, the file will get much larger for a given image size, and could easily be larger even for smaller output sizes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho input and output both images are in JPEG format, so I think image size should be lesser.

Comment: _"input and output both images are in JPEG format, so I think image size should be lesser"_ -- There's no reason to believe that would be true, not without additional details. If the original image is compressed e.g. with a quality setting of 10% and then saved (even at a smaller size) with a quality setting of 90%, the file size will be _much_ larger.